# as3 - flvplayback component - disable auto buffer?

Tags: actionscript-3, flv, playback

I'm using the flvplayback component in an AS3 movieclip. I do have the source defined in the compontents properties to a video hosted on Amazon s3.

Now the problem is as soon as the swf loads in a browser it starts downloading/buffering the video even though it's not set to autoplay.

Is it possible to only have it start downloading if the play button is clicked (I do have a custom play button hooked up to player via AS3)? I have 3 separate video players in the swf each with fairly large videos and I don't really want to burn through a ton of bandwidth especially if the user only plays one video.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't used the flvplaybackcomponent, but I'm assuming as soon as you specify a url, it'll start downloading.  Try either not setting that until it's been interacted with, or -- do what everyone else does -- place an clickable image on top, then once that's done, create your video player.